# How to make it ternary?

Tags: python, class

```py
first_num = int(input("First number >>> "))
second_num = int(input("Second number >>> "))

if first_num >= second_num:
    diff = first_num - second_num
else:
    diff = second_num - first_num

print(f"The absolute difference of {first_num} and {second_num} is {diff}.")
```

Comment: Hi @Lazygameer. What programming language is this? If you tag it with the language, the question will be more visible to people who know that language.

Comment: @DominicCronin, based on the source, it's Python, so I added that tag (and formatted the code).

Comment: Why ternary? ``diff = abs(first_num - second_num)`` would be more appropriate to represent what is actually being done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Python, although you haven't been clear.

```
first_num = int(input("First number >>>"))
second_num = int(input("Second number >>>"))

# Here is the ternary part: Python doesn't have an explicit ternary
# operator like C/C++, but does have this more compact if/else syntax
# which acts like one
difference = (first_num - second_num) if (first_num > second_num) else (second_num - first_num)

printf(f'The absolute difference of {first_num} and {second_num} is {difference}')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a reasonably simple one in that it follows the form `something if condition else something_else`:

```py
diff = first_num - second_num if first_num >= second_num else second_num - first_num
```

But, to be honest, if you want the absolute value, just use the `abs()` function:

```py
diff = abs(first_num - second_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator by using 'if' statement.

In your code,

diff = first_num-second_num if first_num>=second_num else second_num-first_num

The format is as follows,

diff = (exp1) if (condition) else (exp2)

Comment: Got that, updating the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need any ternary logic at all, because Python has a built-in `abs()` function which will return the absolute:

```
first_num = int(input("First number >>> "))
second_num = int(input("Second number >>> "))

print(f"The absolute difference of {first_num} and {second_num} is {abs(first_num - second_num)}")
```